# How can TCP header announce LAN IP over Public IP in tracker System?

Tags: bittorrent

**I have hosted a xbtit tracker on a VPS server.I have uploaded a file and my friend who is on may LAN had downloaded it.But while he was downloading he did not get LAN speed which he was supposed to get.In the Peer instead of his LAN IP his Public IP was deteted.And so he downloaded at slow speed.

How can TCP header announce LAN IP over Public IP in tracker system ?
Is there any small php code ?

When i used to host the server on LAN there was no such problems.ANd all my users who will be using this tracker are my ISP LAN users.SO i need sopmething so that in the peerlist their LAN IP gets detected over Public IP

SOmebody please help me

Comment: not sure quite what your app is, but in theory the private ip could be included as data so you see IP (not there) go deeper/further, you see TCP. go deeper/further you see Application layer protocol go a bit further and you see its data and anything can be there. your girlfriend's height, weight, maybe photo if room, maybe address if room, and if you want, your computer's private ip.  but probably the bit torrent protocol would  have to be abused a little somehow to smuggle that in.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are wanting is not really practical  (and I can understand why someone gave this a -1, although it was not me).

I'll try to unravel it a bit for you -

When (home) computers are on a LAN, they typically share an "invalid" range of addresses, which the router then rewrites as a valid IP address - a process called NAT - this appears to be the case with your LAN.

A web server uses TCP (normally on port 80).  Most web servers will be able to provide information about the computer connecting to it based on 2 factors - the data it receives - Which purport to be coming from the router, not the computer - and headers given by the web client.  None of these factors include the LAN address of the client where the LAN address has been NAT'ed - indeed to do so would be a security hole with (for the most part) no value.   This is the fundamental problem you are having.

Thus the answer to the next part of your question is "No, you can't write a piece of PHP to announce the local IP, as it never receives the local IP".   Also, to do so would be against the spirit of Bittorrent - sorry, but sharing a file using BT EXTERNALLY for local use is outside its design parameters - that kind of problem can be resolved using filesharing.

If you want to work around the problem you need to either move the Tracker into the LAN or connect the external VPS to your LAN across a VPN so as to "defeat" NAT between the locations.  That said, if you are asking these questions, you probably have A LOT of learning to do prior to embarking on setting up a VLAN which will work for you.

Comment: you write "an 'invalid' range of addresses"  OUCH.  You mean private range of addresses, as listed in RFC 1918.

Comment: Note that some clients will attempt to search for other clients on the same LAN and do LAN sharing that way, but that is a per client feature and not a feature of the bittorrent protocol itself.

Comment: @barlop - Yes, you are correct, and I am aware of RFC1918 (including the 172.16/12 range most people dont recognise !).  I deliberately tried to keep my answer simple, hence why the word invalid was in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that there's not any practical solution for your problem.

However, I can think of only one alternative way to your problem.

You may setup a bittorrent tracker on your local network and tell the main tracker (which is on the www) to add an announce url of your local torrent tracker automatically while downloading the torrent.

This is possible with [php](/questions/tagged/php). The script `xbtit` you are using uses a torrent encoding and decoding method called [`BEncode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) and `BDecode`.
You may add or remove tracker urls during the BEncoding process.

You may develop some php code to check the downloader's request url if it's within your IP range. If it's a match, you may add your local tracker's announce url within the array of `"announce-list"`.
Configure your local torrent tracker to track any torrent to any user. See [XBTT Documentation](http://xbtt.sourceforge.net/tracker/).

Now your local network users within your LAN can download the torrent and get announced within your local network, connect to each other and download.

Comment: Hi there......... I have a different types of problem.... my xbtit works on local ip but not working on my public ip or domain......
please help me.. 
no one understand my topic please help...

Answer (score 0):

On Your Tracker Setting

Tick Allow External Torrents

UnTick Disable DHT

unTick Private Scrape

Untick Private Announce

Comment: Hi there......... I have a different types of problem.... my xbtit works on local ip but not working on my public ip or domain......
please help me.. 
no one understand my topic please help...